What is the image of Re(z)>1 under this transformation?
What is the image of $Re(z)>1$ under $w=(-1+i)z-2+3i$
Due to $-1+i$, that means I have to rotate $Re(z)>1$ by $135^o$ right? How do I do that?
Edit: To be exact, I found this on a textbook
Show that the image of the right half plane Re(z) > 1 under the linear transformation w = (−1 + i)z − 2 + 3i is the half plane v > u + 7.
Thanks in advance.

Welcome to MSE. Your question as it is currently written is not entirely clear. When you say image, are you changing variables from $z$ to $w$? What makes you think that this is a rotation? Any details such as this will really improve your question and increase the chances of quality answers.

Noted, thanks. I edited the question.

You only need to consider the boundary $Re(z)=1$, so it can be parameterized as $1+ti$. Put it into the transformation then you get your image's boundary.
